# Move files inside the cloudstorage from gae

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing an app where the user can upload pictures to the cloudstorage, from gae. Making the upload was a little tricky, because I had to convert the uploaded file to a byte format. I followed the next tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview

I only replaced

```
  writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap
               ("And miles to go before I sleep.".getBytes()));
```

with

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream))
writeChannel.write(buffer)
```

Now I must rename some folders/images. I read the related doc about it, and I tried to read the original file and rewrite it in the new location. But I'm having a lot of problems to read the file as bytefile, and rewrite it (I guess I must read as bytefile).

My last attempt was something like this:

```
  public void copyFile(String from,String to) {
        FileService   fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService
        AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile(from)

        readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile,true)      
        int fileSize = fileService.stat(readableFile).getLength.intValue()
        LOG.info("Size int " + fileSize)
        ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(fileSize)

        readChannel.read(dst)

        //readChannel.close() comment because fails to close the file.

        GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
          .setBucket("bucket_name")
          .setKey(to)
          .setAcl("public_read")

        AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder.build())
        val writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, true)

        // This time we write to the channel directly.
        writeChannel.write(dst)

        // Now finalize
        writeChannel.closeFinally()
        readChannel.close()
}
```

When I use this method, it writes the file, but with 0 bytes. Any ideas?

Comment: Never played with Java.. you can try my example of uploading stuff on CloudStorage or Blobstore using Python for GAE.. http://upload.gae-init.appspot.com/resource/upload/

Comment: Thanks, but my project is entirely in java and i can't add python.

Comment: Hello @vmariano, did you able to move images using new cloud storage APi?

Comment: @nsgulliver mmm, i moved out of the project i can´t test it now.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileService` is deprecated. Check out the Cloud Storage API, there is a [`objects.copy`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy) method that you could use.

You would then have to delete the file using [`objects.delete`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/delete).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your read is succeeding and the data is there as you expect? [`FileReadChannel`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileReadChannel) inherits the `read()` method from [`ReadableByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html) whose docs say:

> Returns:
>   The number of bytes read, possibly zero, or -1 if the channel has reached end-of-stream

Your code is not checking that the return value from `read()` equals `fileSize` so the error could be there, and if the buffer is empty, it would explain why your code is creating an empty file.

Also, this line:

```
// readChannel.close() comment because fails to close the file.
```

is concerning as it suggests that there are other problems, as it shouldn't fail. Is the file you're trying to read (a) readable and (b) finalized?

---

Separately, as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654764/david) mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23784255/3618671), the Files API you are using is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/):

> **Deprecation Notice:** The Files API feature is going to be removed at some time in the future, replaced by the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/). The documentation for the deprecated API is retained for the convenience of developers still using the Files API.

So, as the directions suggest, please see [Google Cloud Storage Java Client library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) and check out the [migration page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/migrate) for the mapping from the deprecated API calls to the new ones, which includes a complete migration example, which should help you in this case.